# Sometimes when changing a page, NextJS redirects me to previous page and returns "warn - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload"

Tags: next.js

Sometimes when changing a page, NextJS redirects me to previous page and returns "warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload" with "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvc4L.png)

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem before. To resolve it, you can try deleting the cached files in Next.js

Locate the `.next` folder in the root directory of your project and remove it. Now, restart your application to see if the issue is resolved.